# How do I send mail right after order is made?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom checkout field that takes a second email address from the customer in addition to the default billing email address field that Woocommerce checkout has.
After the checkout is completed, I want to send an email to both email addresses.
The email is successfully getting sent to the billing email, but not the email from the custom field.

I am using the filter `woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status` to get the `order_id` and send the mails.
And, I am using the action `woocommerce_checkout_fields` to add the custom field, which it is doing successfully.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'my_woocommerce_checkout_fields' );
function my_woocommerce_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
        if( $product_id == 786 ) {
            $fields['billing']['billing_field_byten_email'] = array(
                'label'     => __('Partner Email'),
                'placeholder'   => _x('', 'woocommerce'),
                'required'  => false,
                'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
                'clear'     => true
            );
        }
    }
    return $fields;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status','my_payment_complete_order_status', 10, 2);
function my_payment_complete_order_status( $order_status, $order_id ){
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    $order_billing = $order->get_billing_email();
    $partner_email = $order->get_meta('billing_field_byten_email');
    wp_mail( $order_billing, "Subject test 3", "Message test 3" );
    wp_mail( $partner_email, "Subject test 3", "Message test 3" );
    return $order_status;
    return $order_id;
}
```

I expect it to send email to both email addresses right after order is placed.

Comment: Are the SMTP settings set up properly in the config so that `wp_mail()` works?

Comment: @Havenard Yes, as I said, the email to the billing email address is getting sent successfully.

Comment: Just make sure you have saved you custom meta `billing_field_byten_email` in order properly or you are getting its value within `my_payment_complete_order_status` function.

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can do that usign action `woocommerce_new_order`

```
// Function to send mail
function send_emails($order_id) {
      $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

      $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email();
      $partner_email = $order->billing_field_byten_email

       $send_subject ="Your Subject";
       $send_message = "Your Message";

       //send email
       wp_mail( $billing_email, $send_subject, $send_message );

       wp_mail( $partner_email, $send_subject, $send_message );
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'func_send_emails');
```

Read more about woocommerce hooks [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)